# Show alerts to the user if the app is closed?

Tags: java, android

I have simple app for show pageView with text, I want to notify user at specific time every day to open my app at specific page.
So I test my App by Marshmallow device, I am using alarmManager for this task, but once I close App from main screen notification stop showing.
I used Broadcast Receiver with remote process  `android:process=":remote"` but Alarm not work also I used service also it killed with closing App.
So what is right sequence to achieve this job?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Service`. `AlarmManager` and a `BroadcastReceiver` to restart alarm service on device boot.

Check this example:
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

Comment: I created the application as in the article. But once the application is closed the broadcast does not respond.

Comment: I test my App on HUAWEI device in developer mode , it may causes that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

When I was making alarm clock app for me Service with WAKE_LOCK was waking up the phone when it was blocked or the app was killed by user.
This class(with some notification displayed) is preventing app from being killed :
https://github.com/mrkostua/SmartAlarm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mrkostua/mathalarm/alarms/mathAlarm/services/WakeLockService.kt
So after scheduled intent can be send to BroadcastReceiver.